# Mysql - timestamp column not updating

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a User table with a column, last_login, of type timestamp. Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_login` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `facebook_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

I want to update it when a user logs in with the current timestamp. I do:

```
 $sql = "Update User set last_login = ".time()."
         Where id = :id";

 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
 $stmt->bindParam("id", $user->id);
 $stmt->execute();
```

In the mysql log file I can see this query is getting executed:

```
 Update User set last_login = 1381949425 Where id = '1'
```

But somehow, it says "no rows affected". How is this possible? There is a user in the table with id of 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a MySQL person, not a PHP (?) person but what that query *should* cause on the MySQL side is this:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '1381949425' for column 'last_login' at row 1
```

Timestamp columns store their value in epoch seconds, but they expect datetime literals, not integers.

```
$sql = "Update User set last_login = FROM_UNIXTIME(".time().")
     Where id = :id";
```

...or...

```
$sql = "Update User set last_login = NOW() Where id = :id";
```

Unless you have a reason to use the time() function in your application, the `NOW()` function in MySQL will do the same thing.

Comment: `NOW()` is the ideal answer